# Message consuming and publishing from and to IBM Mq slowing down

Tags: spring-boot, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I have a Spring boot application which consumes messages from IBM Mq, processes and further publishes processed message to a topic string. The inbound messages are around between 5000 - 20000 messages/minute. PFB the code and configurations that I am using.  With the below implementation the application runs w/o issues for a day or more nd then suddenly the messages in the input queue start backing up and processing becomes slow. On checking the dynatrace, the consuming is fast but the message publishing to the topic string is taking more time. I need help in understanding if there is something wrong with my implementation.

**AsyncConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
public class AsyncConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private LogService logger;

    @Autowired
    private Servers configProperties;

 @Bean(name = "asyncTaskExecutor")
    public ExecutorService getAsyncTaskExecutor() {
        // Max Thread pool size is 32
        String K_THREAD_POOL = "k-th-pool-";
        return getExecutor(K_THREAD_POOL, 32);
    }

    private ExecutorService getExecutor(String threadName, int maxPoolSize) {
        final ThreadFactory threadFactory = new CustomizableThreadFactory(threadName);
     
            ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, maxPoolSize,
                    60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>(), threadFactory);
            threadPoolExecutor.setRejectedExecutionHandler((r, executor) -> {
                if (!executor.isShutdown()) {
                    try {
                        executor.getQueue().put(r);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        throw new RejectedExecutionException(e);
                    }
                }
            });
            return threadPoolExecutor;
     
    }   
}
```

**MqConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class MqConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private LogService logger;

    @Autowired
    private Servers configProperties;

    @Bean(name = "mqConnectionFactory")
    @Primary
    public ConnectionFactory mqConnectionFactory() {
        MQConnectionFactory mqConnectionFactory = new MQConnectionFactory();
        try {
            mqConnectionFactory.setHostName(configProperties.getHost());
            mqConnectionFactory.setQueueManager(configProperties.getQueueManager());
            mqConnectionFactory.setPort(Integer.valueOf(configProperties.getPort()));
            mqConnectionFactory.setChannel(configProperties.getChannel());
            mqConnectionFactory.setAppName("app1");
            mqConnectionFactory.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
            mqConnectionFactory.setCCSID(1208);
            mqConnectionFactory.setClientReconnectOptions(WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT);
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.logError(mqConnectionFactory, 
                    "Failed to create MQConnectionFactory", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.toString(), e, new ServiceMetrics());
        }
        return mqConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean(name = "cachingConnectionFactory")
    public CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory(ConnectionFactory mqConnectionFactory){
        CachingConnectionFactory factory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
        factory.setSessionCacheSize(1);
        factory.setTargetConnectionFactory(mqConnectionFactory);
        factory.setReconnectOnException(true);
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean(name = "messageListenerContainerFactory")
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory provideJmsListenerContainerFactory(
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        factory.setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handleError(Throwable t) {
                ServiceMetrics metrics = new ServiceMetrics();
                metrics.setCorrelationId(UUID.getUUID());
                logger.logError(factory, 
                        "Exception occurred at JMS Factory Container Listener", t,
                        metrics);
            }
        });
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean(name = "jmsQueueTemplate")
    public JmsTemplate provideJmsQueueTemplate(CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory) {
        return new JmsTemplate(cachingConnectionFactory);
    }

    @Bean(name = "jmsTopicTemplate")
    public JmsTemplate provideJmsTopicContainerFactory(CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory) {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(cachingConnectionFactory);
        jmsTemplate.setPubSubDomain(true);
        return jmsTemplate;
    }
}
```

**MessageInputQueueListener.java**

```
@Component
public class MessageInputQueueListener {

    @Autowired
    private LogService logger;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("jmsTopicTemplate")
    private JmsTemplate jmsTopicTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private ExecutorService asyncTaskExecutor;

    @JmsListener(destination = "${mqserver.queue}", containerFactory = "sigRouteMessageListenerContainerFactory",
            concurrency = "1-12")
    public void receiveSigroute(Message message) {

        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> processSigrouteMessage(message), asyncTaskExecutor);
    }
    
    private void processSigrouteMessage(final Message message){
    
        // processing the message and get the processed message to publish.
        --
        publishMessage(processedMessage);
        message.acknowledge();
    
    }
    
    

    private void publishMessage(String messageString) {
        jmsTopicTemplate.convertAndSend(topicString, messageString);

    }
}
```

Comment: If you suspect the publishing side is getting gradually slower and slower, can you tell us more about that side of things. For example, is the number of subscribers constant over this time period, or is the number of subscribers growing (that would certainly be a reason for a publish to be slower if more messages have to be put as a result of the publish)? If the subscriber numbers are constant, are they all keeping up with the messages being sent to them, or are their subscriber queues getting deeper and deeper?

Comment: By Subscribers do you mean message Listeners? If so there are a constant set of listeners. If you look at the above code snippet I have Listener concurrency set to 1-12 and we have a total of 10 instances running on PCF and for publishing I am using caching connecting factory with the session cache size set to 1

Comment: By subscribers, I mean how many applications are subscribed to the topic you are publishing on. You can see this in MQ by using the following MQSC command: `DISPLAY TPSTATUS(your-topicString) TYPE(SUB)`

Comment: we only have 1 subscriber and that also has 10 instance on PCF

Comment: I can't imagine how only 1 subscriber would cause the publish to get slower and slower. Are you using the same topic string every time? If you have a new unique topic string each time then your topic tree would be gradually growing in size, perhaps that could slow it down. Your code doesn't show us where the `topicString` comes from - can you tell us a little more about that?

Comment: The topic string is a constant value. It is defined in the application yml.